# Why not kill Lucifer with the angel knife?

Tags: supernatural

I have seen all the episodes of Supernatural, going back on the 5th season, when they are trying to kill Lucifer, why not just use the angel knife? The Colt didn't work, the demon knife won't work because he is an angel. I mean if they got close enough to put the gun to his head, couldn't they just have used the angel knife on him?

Answer (score 2):

Lucifer is an archangel and can't be killed with an angelblade. Only an archangel's sword could do the trick, and those are hard to come by.

It should be noted that we've seen ultra-powerful weapons besides the Colt and archangel swords. Death's scythe comes to mind, it's unknown whether this would be capable of doing so. Though, Crowley likely thought the odds of it working low, since he presented it to Dean himself as an indirect means of defeating Lucifer.